# How can I clear this map in Tiny Brains?

Tags: tiny-brains

[image: Tiny Brains stuck map]

How can I clear this map? Stomping machine is too fast to walk through.

Answer (score -1):

push an iceblock across and swap with it

Comment: This answer is not correct. Did you mean 'Make an ice, Jump onto the ice, change character and swap'? Then negative, you can't. Only the ice goes to right, and character still remains left. height(character + ice) < height(Max height of moving bar)

Comment: @user68521 no just push the iceblock across and then swap with the iceblock